# GraphQLError: Names must start with [_a-zA-Z] but "$e" does not on Heroku but not localhost

Tags: heroku, graphql

I'm trying to deploy a prisma / graphql / nest.js app to Heroku but am getting failures on Heroku with this error:

GraphQLError: Names must start with [_a-zA-Z] but "$e" does not.

It doesn't happen on localhost - I can connect to the database on Heroku from local and everything works fine.  There is no line or error code - I've checked my schema.prisma and my graphql files and can't find anything that starts with a $.